# ensureIndex({ title: "text" }) not working - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to make the 'title' property of a 'book' object searchable.

I have been following [these steps](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-text-index-on-multiple-fields/) on how to create a text index on a specific property, and [these steps](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/search-for-text/) on how to search a field, however I seem to get an error.

```
mongo
use library
db.books.ensureIndex({ title: "text" })
db.books.insert({title: "JavaScript The Good Parts"});
db.books.runCommand( "text", { search: "javascript" } )
{
    "errmsg" : "no such cmd: text",
    "bad cmd" : {
         "text" : "books",
         "search" : "javascript"
    },
    "ok" : 0
}
```

Can anyone advise where I might be going wrong?
Thanks

MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8

Comment: Have you enabled [text search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-text-search/)?

Comment: He enabled it, because otherwise he would receive error on the ensureIndex part.

Comment: Try to do `use admin` and after this `db.runCommand( { setParameter: 1, textSearchEnabled: 1 } )`. In my case it helped. What I found strange is that you did not have error on putting the indexes.

Comment: Thanks @SalvadorDali, Can you put that in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do `use admin` and after this:

```
db.runCommand({
  setParameter: 1,
  textSearchEnabled: 1
})
```

In my case it helped. What I found strange is that you did not have error on putting the indexes. Because if you would have this error you have to just [enable text search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-text-search/) on start.